# Há como obter o "value" de um "select" pelo PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou tentando pegar o `id` de um produto através de uma função jQuery, porém eu preciso passar esta variável para o php, e como este trecho do código PHP já está dentro do `<script></script>` não funciona da maneira que fiz abaixo, então gostaria de saber se há uma maneira para pegar este valor diretamente no trecho PHP, ou se há uma outra maneira de obter este valor.
Lembrando que eu pego o valor apenas depois de selecionar uma opção.

```
<select name="txt_os" id="txt_os" class="so">
    <option value="-1">Selecione uma opção</option>
    <?php
        while($linha = self::listar($qry))
        {
            echo "<option value=$linha[id]> $linha[titulo]</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
</select>


<script>
    var id = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".so").change(function(){
            if (parseFloat($(this).val()) != -1)
            {
              id[0] = parseInt($(this).val());
              alert(id[0]);

              "<?php
                $idG = "<script>document.write(id[0])</script>";
                $sqlG = "SELECT * FROM gabinete WHERE id='$idG'";

                $g-> verDados($sqlG, 0);

                $precoG         = $g->getPreco();
              ?>"

              precoG = "<?php echo $precoG?>";
              alert(precoG);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Trocando

```
$idG = "<script>document.write(id[0])</script>";
```

por

```
$idG = "1";
```

Funciona normalmente, porém eu mesmo determinaria o resultado, o que não é a ideia.

Comment: Mostra o id que está na opção selecionada no primeiro, no segundo o resultado é vazio.

Comment: Mas que segundo?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto tem dois alert no código, alert(id[0]); e alert(precoG);

Comment: O problema é esse document.write(). Já que o PHP está enfiado no Javascript, depois do sinal de igualdade de **$idG** você fecha as aspas duplas, concatena com o sinal de mais (+) coloca a variável do JS normal, concatena de novo e reabre as aspas duplas

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ficaria assim então:
    "<?php
        $idG = " + id[0] + ";
 $sqlG ....

?
Se for não funcionou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Misturar PHP com HTML apesar de errado é aceitável, agora misturar PHP com JavaScript, 99% das vezes é a pior união que pode ocorrer.

Separe tudo, o máximo que pude, e use AJAX. Algo assim:

**HTML**

```
<select name="txt_os" id="txt_os" class="so">
    <option value="-1">Selecione uma opção</option>
    <?php
        while($linha = self::listar($qry))
        {
            echo "<option value=$linha[id]> $linha[titulo]</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    //var id = parseInt( $( this ).val() );

    var id = 123; // Valor fictício.

    $.get( 'getPreco.php', { 'id': id }, function( data ) {

        alert( data.preco );

    }, 'json' );
});
```

**getPreco.php**

```
<?php

// APENAS para facilitar o debug

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );

$idG = ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL );

if( is_null( $idG ) ) {
    // Erro: Sem ID
}

//$sqlG = "SELECT * FROM gabinete WHERE id='$idG'";

//$g-> verDados($sqlG, 0);

// Informação fictícia. Usando o ID passado como preço

header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Opcional

echo json_encode( array( 'preco' => $idG ) );
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém eu fiz desta forma e o valor que retronou ficou como "undefined", saberia me dizer alguma motivo para isso acontecer?

Comment: Por isso eu disse *algo assim*. Não é pra você copiar, colar e esperar que funcione. O que eu fiz foi simplesmente separar o que você já tinha de forma mais lógica. Modifiquei algumas coisinhas mas quem vai dizer se está certo ou não é você. Se você recebeu um undefined no JS, o erro está no **getPreco.php**. Acesse esse arquivo e passe um parâmetro GET (`getPreco.php?id=123`) e veja se aparece algum erro no browser. Se aparecer, corrija. Se não aparecer verifique se o JSON gerado por json_encode() está em conformidade com aquilo que o JS está usando.

Comment: eu já tinha testado de diversas maneira, só não passando o id desta forma: (getPreco.php?id=1). eu não modifiquei nada no código do getPreco.php e o que é apresentado em tela é isso, {"preco":"199.99"}, exatamente o que deveria apresentar

Comment: fiz um outro teste, substitui o json_encode por apenas isso echo $g->getPreco(), e funcionou, porém eu preciso do array, tive um problema semelhante em outro código que eu resolvi com isso 'header('Content-type: application/json');', mas colocando isso não a retorno algum

Comment: Se você viu `{"preco":"199.99"}` é um bom sinal, o JSON está sendo gerado corretamente. Você recebeu um *undefined* no JavaScript então o erro é só nele. Dá uma olhada com o quê a variável **precoG** do JavaScript está sendo populada e o que você tem no seu JSON.

Comment: desculpa, mas não entendi o que você quis dizer com "a variável precoG do JavaScript está sendo populada", e como eu faço para ver o que tenho no JSON? :P

Comment: Acessando a URL manualmente ou abrindo o Console do navegador, clicando na requisição feita para **getPreco.php** e vendo o que diz na aba Resposta. Você havia tentado usar uma variável PHP chamada **$precoG**. Quando eu reescrevi eu montei o JSON do mesmo jeito e a variável do JavaScript **precoG** estava sendo populada com o índice **precoG** do JSON de retorno. O seu *output* mostra um índice **preco** e não **precoG**. Como você simplesmente copiou, gerou um *undefined* porque não existe nenhum índice **precoG** no seu JSON.

Comment: na verdade eu não copiei 100%, eu arrumei o que precisava, e troquei precoG por preco, tanto em getPreco.php quanto no código principal.

Comment: Resta registrar o que **data** tem então. Dentro daquela função do $.get coloque `console.log(data)` e veja o que o aparece no console. E seja lá quem foi que negativou a resposta sem comentar e nem tentar ajudar, obrigado.

Comment: coloquei o console.log(data), e o que aparece é isso:{"preco":"299"} mas se colocar console.log(data.preco) fica como undefined

Comment: *Ô zica...* Eu tinha certeza de que o código estava correto, mas por eu ter acabado confiando na "inteligência" da jQuery em adivinhar o tipos dos dados em trânsito, assumi que o argumento **data** disponível no callback de sucesso seria um JSON válido. Mas pelo visto acabou que ele era um texto plano e por isso não funcionava. Force o tipo de retorno para json conforme a edição que eu fiz na resposta e vai funcionar.

Comment: Ô zica MESMO... fiz a modificação e agora não está mais entrando na função ajax :/

Comment: Dê uma revisada, você deve ter feito alguma coisa a mais ou menos, porque eu testei (não com informações do banco de dados, claro) e funcionou. Revisei o JS e o PHP e editei pra deixar mais mastigada a solução.

Comment: demorei pra voltar, mas seguinte, fiz mil e uma revisões e não encontrei nada que possa estar errado, mas se trocar a requisição JSON por HTML funciona(claro que tirando os array de retorno), com json não entra na função sucsses.

Comment: Poste o que tem num [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), edite a resposta original com o link pra versão atualizada. Mesmo que o JSFiddle não vá rodar o PHP é só para eu ter uma idéia de como está.

Comment: estava fazendo sem a interação com o banco de dados para colocar no JSFiddle, e ao testar funcionou normal, tem ideia de pq não funcionar por JSON com a conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: Alguma coisa no seu PHP está errada. Habilite os erros e veja o que é.